# Python inheritance: init is having an issue with the number of params

Tags: python, django, class, inheritance

I'm developing a basic python Class-Subclass system for my Django project, but i'm experiencing a strange issue.

First of all, the definition of the classes:

file classes.py

```
class BaseAd(object):
    """ base class for all the ads, with common parameters """

    def __init__(self, dom, web, loc, cc, a, c, date, desc, hl, **kwargs):
        self.domain = self.doDomain(dom)
        self.url = self.doUrl(web)
        self.description = self.doDescription(desc, hl)
        self.location = self.doLocation(a, c, loc)
        self.date = self.doDate(date)
```

file jobs.py

```
class JobAd(BaseAd):
    """ extends BaseAd with more parameters """

    def __init__(self, domain, url, location, countrycode, area, city, 
                 index_date, description, 
                 contract_multivalue, salary_min, company, job_title, **kwargs):

        self.contract_type = self.doContract(contract_multivalue)
        self.salary = self.doSalary(salary_min)
        self.company = self.doCompany(company)
        self.title = self.doTitle(job_title)

        """ Super constructor call """
        super(JobAd, self).__init__(
            domain,
            url,
            location,
            countrycode,
            area,
            city,
            index_date,
            description,
            **kwargs
        )
```

Both of the classes have their respective methods (doDomain, doSalary etc) which are irrelevant now, since they just return the string they get as input (will be implemented better in the future, now is just not needed). The kwargs is just used to store some non-useful but still returned params of the original dict (otherwise i'll get an error)

The JobAd class is used as a constructor parameter for our python-to-solr interface [sunburnt](https://github.com/tow/sunburnt). After you define a class and pass it to the method, it translates fields defined in the solr response (which is simply a dict) into the class. So, params defined in JobAd's init must have the same name as their definition in the solr schema.

this is the actual constructor call:

```
/path/to/myapp/resultsets/views_json.py in job_search_json
        #lines splitted for better reading
        #res is a solr search object

        items = res.paginate(start=start, rows=res_per_page)
        .sort_by("-index_date")
        .sort_by("-score")
        .sort_by("-md5")
        .sort_by("-posted_date")
        .execute(constructor=JobAd)
```

next in the stacktrace there is:

```
/path/to/sunburnt-0.6-py2.7.egg/sunburnt/search.py in execute

        return self.transform_result(result, constructor)

    ...

▼ Local vars
Variable         Value
self             sunburnt.search.SolrSearch object at 0x7f8136e78450
result           sunburnt.schema.SolrResponse object at 0x7f8136e783d0
constructor      class 'myapp.models.jobs.JobAd'
```

and finally

```
/path/to/sunburnt-0.6-py2.7.egg/sunburnt/search.py in transform_result

            result.result.docs = [constructor(**d) for d in result.result.docs]
```

inside the last "local vars" tab, there is the result dictionary (just the structure, not the full dict with values):

```
self    sunburnt.search.SolrSearch object at 0x7f8136e78450
d      {'area': 
        'city': 
        'contract_multivalue': 
        'country': 
        'countrycode': 
        'currency': 
        'description': 
        'district': 
        'domain': 
        'fileName': 
        'index_date':
        'job_experience':
        'job_field_multivalue':
        'job_position_multivalue': 
        'job_title':
        'job_title_fac':
        'latitude': 
        'location': 
        'longitude': 
        'md5':
        'salary_max': 
        'salary_min': 
        'study':
        'url':
        'urlPage':
        }

constructor    class 'tothego_frontend.sito_maynard.models.jobs.JobAd'
```

In the django.log file, there's no other error, except the DogSlow trap telling nothing other than the trapped line.

This is the error i'm getting:

```
TypeError at /jobs/us/search/

__init__() takes exactly 13 arguments (12 given)
```

The behaviour i'm expecting is not the behaviour i'm actually experiencing: instead of having my class call its parent's constructor (10 arguments), it's using its own init (14 arguments).

I've been trying also with old python class definition: no "object" in the superclass; inside the subclass' init, parent class is initialized as BaseAd.**init**(self,...); also i've been trying to call the super method as first statement inside the subclass' init (a la java) but nothing seems to change.

What am i doing wrong here?

EDIT: i fixed the length of the second init line, was a bit too much!

**ADDED INFORMATIONS FROM DJANGO'S STACKTRACE AS ASKED**

Latest tought: i'm starting to assume that sunburnt doesn't support class inheritance, even if there's nothing about it in the docs.

**NEW EDIT**: after some tests today, this is what i've discovered (so far)

- sunburnt allows inheritance
- i had 3 parameters out of sync, updated the code and the error

Now it's always missing an argument. The "self" maybe? I really don't know where to look anymore, the error is the same as before (same stacktrace) just different wrong parameters.

**FOUND THE PROBLEM** actually, adding some default values to the init parameters helped me out spot the real error: missing fields in the input. Sorry guys for waisting your time and thank you again for counseling

Comment: You need to show the code that's actually instantiating the objects.

Comment: Does this class actually have any methods? It might be easier as a dict.

Comment: If I get this correctly, it looks like the problem is in sunburnt?

Comment: Please post the full stacktrace.

Comment: Yes, those classes needs methods and i designed them to wrap the dict i receive as response. For the full stacktrace, later today or tomorrow i'll do it, i tought it was my bad design of the classes, so didn't post it first time! Thanks all in advance for your interest in this btw!

Answer (score 1):

I've taken your code (removing the `do*` methods from the `__init__`s) and turned into a simpler example to try to recreate your problem as you state it.

```
class BaseAd(object):
    """ base class for all the ads, with common parameters """

    def __init__(self, dom, web, loc, cc, a, c, date, desc, hl, **kwargs):
        self.domain = dom
        self.url = web
        self.description = desc
        self.location = loc
        self.date = date

class JobAd(BaseAd):
    """ extends BaseAd with more parameters """

    def __init__(self, domain, url, location, countrycode, area, city, 
                 index_date, description, solr_highlights, 
                 contract_type, salary, company, job_title, **kwargs):

        self.contract_type = contract_type
        self.salary = salary
        self.company = company
        self.title = job_title

        """ Super constructor call """
        super(JobAd, self).__init__(
            domain,
            url,
            location,
            countrycode,
            area,
            city,
            index_date,
            description,
            solr_highlights,
            **kwargs
        )

j = JobAd(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,kwarg1="foo",kwarg2="bar")
```

When running python 2.7.2, this executes fine with no errors. I suggest that perhaps the `__init__` being referred to in the error is `JobAd`s not the super's as `JobAd`'s init actually has 14 arguments, which is what the error is complaining about. I suggest trying to find a place where JobAdd's `__init__` is called with an insufficient number of arguments.

As others have said, posting the full stack trace and showing how JobAd is used is invaluable to determining the root cause.

Comment: Ok, will do it first thing tomorrow! Actually all the parameters passed to JobAd creation are fine (14) as far as i can remember, but wil post the complete stacktrace of the call iside sunburnt